# JQPlot or other JavaScript library - X axis data strips

Tags: javascript, charts, plot, jqplot, highlight

I have to display certain statistical data onto a chart (either Bar Graph or Line Chart) which represent daily totals of some value. One of the things I need to somehow do is mark Weekends and other arbitrary dates with a different background color than the rest of the graph. I am not sure exactly what that's called (some call it highlighting, others call it axis strips, etc...) but I haven't been able to find a solution for JQPlot.

Since it's not just date related (I also have to do this sometimes for integer values as well) I need some solution that supports adding custom ranges to the X axis (series axis) that I can choose the coloring for.

Any hints?

Comment: please be very specific in your question. your question is very generic for this forum. please visit jqplot.com for all the possible graphs solutions form jqplot.

Comment: How is it a generic question? I want to change the background color of the graph only on certain ranges (to have value strips in different colors).

Comment: JQPlot website documentation leaves a lot to be desired, I combed over it a number of times.

Comment: Which kind of chart do you want to display? Linecharts, pie-/donutcharts, barcharts, bubble plots or something complete different?